# sql convert single column to multiple based on delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to "replicate" the excel(data) text to columns function.
basically I have a string column, and I would like to split it to multiple columns based on a specific delimiter.

```
 declare @t table (
    id int,
    name varchar(50)
    )

    insert into @t values (1,'abcd.ef.g')
    insert into @t values (2,'ab.cdef.ghi')
    insert into @t values (3,'a..d')
    insert into @t values (4,'a')

    select * from @t

    id          name
    ----------- --------------------------------------------------
    1           abcd.ef.g
    2           ab.cdef.ghi
    3           a..d
    4           a

    --I would like to get result

    id          name1   name2   name3
    ----------- --------------------------------------------------
    1           abcd    ef      g
    2           ab      cdef    ghi
    3           a       (NULL)  d
    4           a       (NULL)  (NULL)
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: A splitter would be total overkill here. Just use PARSENAME to get the separate elements.

Comment: Actually with your data parsename probably won't work very well but some basic substring logic should do this easily. If possible you should permanently separate this data. Storing delimited data violates 1NF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 declare @t table (id int,name varchar(50))

    insert into @t values (1,'abcd.ef.g')
    insert into @t values (2,'ab.cdef.ghi')
    insert into @t values (3,'a..d')
    insert into @t values (4,'a');



WITH Split_Fields (ID, xmlfields)
AS
(
    SELECT ID ,
    CONVERT(XML,'<Fields><field>'  
    + REPLACE(name,'.', '</field><field>') + '</field></Fields>') AS xmlfields
      FROM @t
)

 SELECT ID      
 ,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[1]','varchar(100)') AS Field1    
 ,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[2]','varchar(100)') AS Field2
 ,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[3]','varchar(100)') AS Field3    
 ,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[4]','varchar(100)') AS Field4
 ,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[5]','varchar(100)') AS Field5
 FROM Split_Fields
```

### Result

```
╔════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ Field1 ║ Field2 ║ Field3 ║ Field4 ║ Field5 ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ abcd   ║ ef     ║ g      ║ NULL   ║ NULL   ║
║  2 ║ ab     ║ cdef   ║ ghi    ║ NULL   ║ NULL   ║
║  3 ║ a      ║        ║ d      ║ NULL   ║ NULL   ║
║  4 ║ a      ║ NULL   ║ NULL   ║ NULL   ║ NULL   ║
╚════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```